# arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1) from Android NDK r8

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I build hello-jni which i got from the sample folder of android-ndk-r5, I got a folloiwng error. Would you please tell me your any idea what i missed?

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
```

Development environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop on WINDOWS 7 via VertualBox
- Android SDK: r08
- Android NDK: r5

detail of error:

```
$ ndk-build
Gdbserver : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile thumb : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
make: *** [/home/users001/android-ndk/samples/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] error1
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

This error went away for me when I used "make" instead of the recommended "make -j4".

Answer (score 0):

I reformed the detail i posted above.

$ ndk-build
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report.
See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html for instructions.
make: *** [/home/user00/android-ndk/samples/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/hello-jni/hello-jni.o] error1

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit. I had plenty of disk space on all partitions.

It disappeared after I upgraded to **Ubuntu 10.10**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my Ubuntu 11.4 VMWare machine. I'm not sure what the root of the issue is.

But rebooting the virtual machine seems to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those having this issue with VMs, the solution that worked for me was bumping up the base memory. It was originally set to 512MB to 1536MB. I'm sure it doesn't have to be that much but it certainly helps.

Comment: Could you explain "bumping up the base memory" in more detail? Do you mean the available RAM for the virtual machine in the e.g. VMWare settings?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.